# Is it possible to whitelist applications from which posts are visible on my Facebook newsfeed?

Tags: facebook

On my Facebook newsfeed, I see posts made by people, and by appliactions such as Farmville, Selective Tweets, random games, etc.

Is there a way by which I can whitelist the apps from which I wish to see posts?

Currently it allows me to blacklist applications, but that doesn’t help with new games and scammy apps being added on a weekly basis. I would rather just whitelist certain known good apps and keep all the rest invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. No such feature exists because of obvious reasons. If they were to allow such feature, people would all whitelist a handful of apps and rest of the apps will never be used, hence making Facebook a bad place for app developers. So, from Facebook's point of view, this feature doesn't make sense.